# If I define addition in the following way, how can I prove that it's commutative?

Tags: proof-writing, induction, natural-numbers, peano-axioms

$a+b=a$, if $b=0$

$a+b=S(a)+S^{-1}(b)$, if $b\not=0$

Here a and b are natural numbers defined according to the Peano axioms, while S represents the successor function.

Basically, I am trying to prove that $\forall a\in N_0\forall b\in N_0(a+b=b+a)$

I am assuming this is supposed to be proved by induction, but I am struggling to come up with a proof.

Comment: For this one I think infinite descent, or the contrapositive of induction, feels easier. That is, suppose you have an example of $a + b \neq b + a$ and find another example which makes a certain natural number smaller. Whether this way or by induction, I think looking at $\max(a,b)$ as the variable to compare cases will be helpful.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA any ideas on how to prove a=0+a?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% clear on how the $S^{-1}$ is to be dealt with formally, but let's assume that your axioms can be rephrased as:

$\forall x \ x + 0 = x \tag{1}$

$\forall x \forall y \ x + S(y) = S(x) + y \tag{2}\label{2}$

or that you can get to these through a fairly easy derivation.

With that, one idea now is to derive the traditional Peano axioms for addition:

$$\forall x \ x + 0 = x \tag{PA1}$$

$$\forall x \forall y \ x + S(y) = S(x + y) \tag{PA2}\label{PA2}$$

In other words, we just need to derive what is traditionally the second axiom for addition.

To do that, they key is to show that:

$$\forall y \forall x \ S(x) + y = S(x + y) \tag{*}\label{*}$$

We can do this by induction over the outside $y$, i.e. show that:

$\forall x \ S(x) + 0 = S(x + 0) \tag{Base}$

$$\text{For any } b: \forall x \ S(x) + b = S(x + b) \to \forall x \ S(x) + S(b) = S(x + S(b)) \tag{Step}$$

For the Base, a simple universal proof will suffice.

For the inductive step, consider some arbitrary $b$, and assume tyhe inductive hypothesis:

$$\forall x \ S(x) + b = S(x + b) \tag{I.H.}\label{I.H.}$$

OK, so now need to show:

$$\forall x \ S(x) + S(b) = S(x + S(b))$$

Again, a good old universal proof will suffice. Consider any arbitrary $a$.

First note that since:

$$a + S(b) \overset{\eqref{2}}{=} S(a) + b$$

we have:

$$S(a) + b = a + S(b) \tag{3}\label{3}$$

So that means:

$$S(a) + S(b) \overset{\eqref{2}}{=} S(S(a)) + b \overset{\eqref{I.H.}}{=} S(S(a) + b) \overset{\eqref{3}}{=} S(a + S(b))$$

which is what we were looking for, thus completing the inductive step.

Once you have $\eqref{*}$, it's now trivial to show $\eqref{PA2}$.

And now you can do all the usual proofs involving the traditional Peano axioms, including commutativity of addition.

Comment: I understand your answer clearly, but I have trouble proving the inductive step that you mentioned, namely that $\forall b\forall x (\ S(x) + b = S(x + b) \implies S(x) + S(b) = S(x + S(b)))$. Could you elaborate a bit more on this specific step?

Comment: @DarkRebellion Sorry, I actually was missing a universal in the consequent there, which may well have confused you. Anyway, I showed some details in the post now.

Comment: I still have one concern. Let's define the induction hypothesis as $P(a,b)\iff S(a)+b=S(a+b)$ During the inductive step, we state that $S(S(a))+b=S(S(a)+b)$, by using the fact that $P(S(a))$, rather than $P(a)$, is true. Are we allowed to do this?

Comment: @DarkRebellion Right. This is exactly why you want to make the inductive hypothesis $P(b) = \forall x \ S(x) + b = S(x+b)$. That is, you have to do the universal proof *inside* the inductive step, rather than the other way around. That way you can apply the inductive hypothesis to both $a$ and $S(a)$.

Comment: It's been almost one month since you wrote this answer, and I finally understand exactly how and why your proof method works, i.e. using induction on the "outside" variable rather than on the "inside" one. I doubt I would have thought of using this induction in this way by myself (my textbooks are almost devoid of proofs in general, let alone something so specific), and this method can be used to prove many, many similiar statements as well. Thank you!

Comment: @DarkRebellion You’re welcome!  And yes, I remember figuring this out many years ago myself no thanks to any textbook!