# Assuming the following definition of the addition of natural numbers, how do I prove that $\forall a:0+a=a$

Tags: proof-writing, induction, natural-numbers, peano-axioms

Natural numbers and the succesor function S are defined according to the Peano axioms.

Addition is defined recursively (DIFFERENTLY from the traditional Peano definition, though I am trying to prove that they are equivalent):

$\forall a:a+0=a$

$\forall a \forall b:a+S(b)=S(a)+b$

I tried and failed to prove this by induction on a.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the set of numbers that verify every property. Let's set: $M=\{n\in \mathbb{N}:n+0=0\}$. $0$ is trivially in $M$. We suppose that there is a natural number $n$ that verifies the given property. Since the sum is defined recursively we have:
$$
S(n)+0=n+S(0)=n+1=S(n)
$$
The other statement is proved similarly.

Answer (score 0):

I showed how you can derive the 'normal' $a + S(b) = S(a+b)$ from what you have in [an earlier post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4452815/if-i-define-addition-in-the-following-way-how-can-i-prove-that-its-commutative/4457853#4457853), and using that, the inductive proof for $0 + a = a$ is trivial.